# Get a histogram of a query Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

The question is:
Show customer's transaction distribution for completed RIDE orders between 1st - 10th of April 2018 (Distribution of customers that have done 1 transaction, 2, 3,4,etc)

And the preview of table that's querying is:

[image]

My query is:

```
SELECT customer_no, COUNT(*) AS total_transaction FROM [bi-dwhdev-01:source.daily_order]
WHERE DATE(order_time) >=  '2018-04-01'AND DATE(order_time) <=  '2018-04-10'
GROUP BY customer_no
ORDER BY total_transaction DESC;
```

I'm wondering how to get a distribution in Bigquery(either Legacy or Standard)?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want two levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT total_transaction, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT customer_no, COUNT(*) AS total_transaction
      FROM [bi-dwhdev-01:source.daily_order]
      WHERE DATE(order_time) >=  '2018-04-01' AND DATE(order_time) <=  '2018-04-10'
      GROUP BY customer_no
     ) c
GROUP BY total_transaction
ORDER BY total_transaction DESC;
```

Comment: But how to draw the histogram?

Comment: @Jane . . . SQL processes data.  It does not create charts.  Import the data into Google Sheets or a similar tool and using the charting tools there.

Comment: Ok! Gotcha. Thanks a lot!